# NSURLSession dataTaskForRequest:completion: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, unrecognized-selector

When trying to create my own session object `NSURLSession()` and request an url I get an unrecognized selector exception but when I use the shared session `NSURLSession.sharedSession()` everything works fine. How come?

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http:/www.google.com")
if url != nil {
    //throws unrecognized selector when dataTaskWithURL is called
    let session=NSURLSession()
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url!)

   //works
    let sharedSession=NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    sharedSession.dataTaskWithURL(url!)
}
```

Comment: Try initializing with configuration. NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You have to [init `URLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/sessionWithConfiguration:) with a configuration:

```
URLSession(configuration: .default)
```

or use shared session

```
URLSession.shared
```

Comment: Thanks It works, I assumed that it have used defaultSessionConfiguration  by default if I don't pass anything to the constructor

Comment: For Swift 3 the syntax is now: 

URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

Answer (score 5):

In SWIFT 3.0 and up:

```
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler:
        {
            (data, response, error) in

            //Your code
        }).resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the shared session `NSURLSession` must be initialized with one of these two methods

```
init(configuration configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration)


init(configuration configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration,
               delegate delegate: NSURLSessionDelegate?,
             delegateQueue queue: NSOperationQueue?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the initialization while declaration :-

```
var session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
```