# Problems with migration to Swift3, compilation error with URLSession.GET

Tags: swift3, migration, nsurlsession, promisekit

I'm trying to migrate from Swift2 to Swift3 and I'm having an issue with URLSession.GET

I went through the migration tool provided by XCode, and changed my "NSURLSession" calls into "URLSession" but I keep having this error message:

```
"Use of Instance member 'GET' on type 'URLSession'; did you mean to use a value of type 'URLSession' instead?"
```

Here is my code:

```
open static func getData() -> Promise<[Station]> {
   return URLSession.GET("http://api.xxx.gov/api/").asDataAndResponse().then { (data: NSData, _) -> [Station] in

     var stations = [Station]()
     // rest of the code to retrieve the data
     ...
     ...

     return stations
    }
}
```

**Update:**
After some digging a found a solution, see answer below for more details and helpful links

Comment: Have you tried URLSession data request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26365148/2098231

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method)

Answer (score -1):

**After some more digging I found a solution :**

First I have to init URLSession with a configuration:

`let URLSession1 = URLSession(configuration: .default)`

Then I can call the 'GET' method and I had to use `(data,_ )` instead of `(data:NSData,_ )`:

```
open static func getData() -> Promise<[Station]> {
   return URLSession1.GET("http://api.xxx.com/api/").asDataAndResponse().then { (data, _) -> [Station] in

    var stations = [Station]()
    // rest of the code to retrieve the data
    ...
    ...
    return stations
  }
}
```

**Some helpful StackOverflow links that helped me find the solution:**

[NSURLSession dataTaskForRequest:completion: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905874/nsurlsession-datataskforrequestcompletion-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instan)